# Search and Replace All the Searched Text in Java TextArea

Tags: java, replace, applet, textarea, space

I have a `Textarea` in an `applet` where the user is supposed to write some text.

I need a code to search what the user wrote and then replace all the spaces "If found" with a "+" sign.

**For Example**: "Hello World" --> "Hello+World".

**My code:**

```
string space = " ";

if textarea.Gettext().contains(space){
space.ReplaceAll("+") }
```

Comment: you should replace the textarea's text instead `space`!!  BTW it does not look like java!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
string space = " ";
textarea.setText(textarea.getText().replaceAll(space, "+"));
```